# Unable to download application OTA iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to distribute a beta version of an app OTA. I'm using team provisioning profile and through Xcode it runs fine on my iPhone. When I click the download link it shows me the usual popup and the app starts downloading but before the progress bar makes any progress I get "Unable to download application at this time". Console shows absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the bundle-identifier key is the same as the one which you have used to build the ipa file. Also bundle-version key should be the same as the one in the ipa

Comment: It is the same. The issue was resolved, it was a problem with the server, not the app.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what was wrong with the server? I'm having the same issues as you did and have a feeling it is related to the server.